# How can I drag a menu item in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, menubar

How can I drag a menu item in Delphi? I'm using `tactionmainmenubar` (at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

When `DesignMode` property of `ActionMainMenuBar` is set to 'true' items are draggable, provided that the `Designable` property of the same is also set 'true'. Note that in design mode items will not function as menu items.